# Problem with serializing a Delphi record with a short string to JSON

Tags: json, delphi, serialization

In our project in Delphi XE 10.2.2, there are tons of records with short string fields.

The problem is that, when we use `TJsonSerializer` from the `System.JSON.Serializers` unit, those fields are ignored.

How can records with short strings be serialized to JSON?

With `AnsiString` and `String` fields, it works fine for sure. The problem is that, like I said before, there are a lot of existing records with short strings.

For example:

```pascal
type
  TTestRec = record
    ShortStrData: string[50];
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  oSerializer: TJsonSerializer;
  r: TTestRec;
begin
  r.ShortStrData := 'short string text';
  oSerializer := TJsonSerializer.Create;
  try
    Memo1.Text := oSerializer.Serialize(r);
  finally
    oSerializer.Free;
  end; 
end;
```

The result is:

```json
{}
```

If we replace `string[50]` with `AnsiString`, the result is as expected:

```json
{"ShortStrData":"short string text"}
```

I assume the problem is in the RTTI, but I'm not sure how to avoid/fix that.

Comment: Unfortunately Delphi compiler does not generate any type information for short-string type. That's why JSON serializer doesn't know how to serialize the field. You can workaround that by defining your own string type `type string50 = string[50];` and use it in the record: `type TTestRec = record ShortStrData: string50; end;`. See also [Is there any way to get RTTI hints for a real48 and shortstring variable in a structure where FieldType is nil in TRttiField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340089).

Comment: There is no Delphi XE 10, last XE version was Delphi XE 8!

Comment: convert your code to use strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, some Object Pascal types (like ShortString and Real48) are not supported by the type information generator. Probably that is related to Delphi classes and objects, like it is mentioned in the documentation:

- In the visibility of class members, any real type except "Real48" can be published.
- "ShortString" is not among the automatable types.

As a consequence, RTTI-based features will not handle those types correctly, like your case with the JSON serializer (which is based on RTTI) that won't serialize fields in those types.

For your problem with "ShortString", you can solve it through a workaround by defining your own string type (and use it in your record later), like this:

```
type
  string50 = string[50];

  TTestRec = record
    ShortStrData: string50;
  end;.
```

But keep in mind that those types are maintained for backward compatibility, especially the "ShortString" which is not supported by mobile compilers, so you have to consider migrating your code base to the newest Object Pascal/Delphi versions.

Comment: Yes, thanks. This what I did and it works as expected.